# initWithCoder doesn't set UILabel property (UIFont and text color)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code for my UICollectionViewCell

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *storyImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *descriptionLabel;

@end

@implementation Story
@synthesize storyImage;
@synthesize titleLabel;
@synthesize descriptionLabel;

    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
    {
        self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
        if (self)
        {
            [self.contentView addSubview:self.titleLabel];
            [self.contentView addSubview:self.descriptionLabel];
            [self.contentView addSubview:self.storyImage];

            [self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kProximaNovaBold size:15]];
            [self.descriptionLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kProximaNova size:13]];
            [self.descriptionLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:140/255.f alpha:1.0]];
            self.descriptionLabel.frame  = CGRectIntegral(self.descriptionLabel.frame);
            self.descriptionLabel.center = roundedCenterPoint(self.descriptionLabel.center);

        }
        return self;
    }
```

but for some reason it's not setting up the property. I'd have to move it out of the init method and put it inside a separate method and call this after calling:

```
 dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath
```

and then it would work. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you checked if self.contentView is nil inside init method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to be doing this stuff in `awakeFromNib:` when everything from the nib has actually been loaded and connected

From the docs for [NSObject UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> **Discussion**
>   The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized.